# Conversity of vector space theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

On watching a video about vector spaces, I comprehend that if $V$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $V$ is a vector space, then $0$ is an element of $V$. Is the converse true; i.e. if $0$ is an element of a proper subset of $\mathbb R^n$ namely $V$, is $V$ a vector space always?

If true, please provide a simple proof. If false, please provide a simple contradiction.

Comment: It is false, and it will be obvious to you in a very short time. Anyway, I do not recommend learning mathematics by watching videos, especially at a basic level. It is much better to read books.

Comment: You are asking if all sets that contain 0 must also satisfy the properties of a vector space. What aspect of this question did you find difficult to answer on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let for example $V=\{0,x\}$ where $x\ne0$ then $x+x=2x\notin V$ and so $V$ isn't closed under addition: it isn't so a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** true if $n\geqslant 1$.

Take for instance $V:=\{0,1\}^n\subset \mathbb R^n$.

You have $0\in V$, but $V$ is not a $\mathbb R$-vector space since $\frac 12\times 1=\frac 12\notin V$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. To be a vector space it must be closed under addition of its elements that is $x+y \in V$ whenever $x,y \in V$ and inverse should exist that is $(-x) \in V$ whenever $x \in V$. Merely $0 \in V$ doesn't guarantee V to b a vector space.